# Baby bearded dragon feeding/digestion

Tags: diet, feeding, bearded-dragon

I have a baby bearded dragon that's 28 days old and haven't had any feeding nor pooping problems until today in the morning.

I ran out of crickets 2 days ago and went to buy more crickets at a different shop that I usually go to. They didn't have any pinhead crickets but they had "small" crickets available and I took them. It had spent about half day without eating that day and fed I with no problems.

This morning I noticed her poop but it had a good part that looked like crickets. I tried feeding her again and didn't want to eat the smallest crickets I have. It would eat them if I dropped a few in the tank - if I grab the pinhead crickets with tweezers or let them crawl on my hand and let her catch them, but she's not interested.

Should I stop feeding her these "small" crickets or should I go purchase actual pinhead crickets?

Answer (score 2):

If they seemed too big for her they may have upset her belly, it happens sometimes that the bugs haven't digested properly. Feel free to feed her some greens as well, a bit easier to digest.

Another thing to consider are parasites, always good to bring a fecal sample to your vet hospital to check, I have yet to look at a sample with no parasites. Those little buggers will cause GI issues, lethargy and innapitence.

Feel free to post a picture of your Beardie and the crickets if you're unsure if they're too big or not. Typical rule of thumb is no bigger then the width of their head.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to tell if your bearded dragon Should be able to eat a cricket is if the cricket is big enough to fit in the gap between their eyes. Never feed a bearded dragon anything bigger than that gap. I have had my bearded dragon since she was a baby and I have always fed her small crickets and she loves them. Unfortunately I don't know what a pinhead is.